# What is the cardinality of the set of Dyck natural numbers of semilength $k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, formal-languages, combinatorics-on-words

In arXiv:2102.02777 ("Recursive Prime Factorizations: Dyck Words as Numbers"), I show that there is a 1:1 correspondence between $\mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ and $\mathcal{D}_{r_{\text{min}}} = \{\epsilon,(),(()),()(()),((())), \ldots\}$.  So what exactly is $\mathcal{D}_{r_{\text{min}}}$? It's the set of *Dyck natural numbers*, i.e., the set of recursive prime factorizations $\{\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}(n) \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}$ is given by Definition 3 below (Definitions 1 and 2 introduce notation for use in Definition 3):

**Definition 1.** The symbol $\frown$ is the string concatenation operator; $a \frown b$ denotes the concatenation of $a$ and $b$.  The concatenation of $a$ and $b$ may also be written in customary fashion as $ab$, provided that doing so does not incur ambiguity.

**Definition 2.** Let $j,k \in \mathbb{N}_{+}$. Then we shall understand $\bigoplus_{i=j}^{k}s_{i}$ to denote the string concatenation $s_{j} \ldots s_{k}$ if $j \le k$, otherwise the empty string $\epsilon$.

**Definition 3.** Let $\Sigma^*$ be the Kleene closure of the set $\{(,)\}$.  Then the *standard nonsurjective recursive prime factorization natural transcription function*, denoted by $\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}$, is given by $\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \Sigma^*$, where

- For $n = 0$, $\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}(n)$ is the empty string $\epsilon$.
- For $n = 1$, $\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}(n)$ is the string $()$.
- For $n > 1$, let $p_{i}$ be the $i$th prime number, let $p_{m}$ be the greatest prime factor of $n$, and let $a = (a_{1}, \ldots, a_{m})$ be the integer sequence satisfying
  \begin{equation}
  n = \prod_{i=1}^{m}p_{i}^{a_{i}}.
  \end{equation}
  Then
  \begin{equation}
  \gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}(n) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m}(\;'('\frown \gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}(a_{i}) \frown ')'\;).
  \end{equation}

Note: It is $\gamma'_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}$ rather than $\gamma_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}$ because I restrict its codomain to yield the bijection $\gamma_{\mathbb{N}_{r}}$ (which I call the *standard RPF natural spelling function*; I do this so that my spelling function will have an inverse, allowing me to map from $\mathcal{D}_{r_{\text{min}}}$ to $N$).  The subscript $\mathbb{N}$ tells us that the function maps natural numbers to Dyck words, in order to distinguish the function from another one that maps *rationals* to Dyck words.  Finally, the subscript $r$ indicates that it involves the right-ascending sequence of prime numbers $(2,3,5,7, \ldots)$, rather than some other prime permutation such as  $(\ldots,7,5,3,2)$ or $(3,2,7,5,\ldots)$.

Now let $S_{k}$ be the subset of $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that every member of $S_{k}$ is represented by a Dyck natural number of semilength $k$.  Then

$S_{0} = \{0\}$

$S_{1} = \{1\}$

$S_{2} = \{2\}$

$S_{3} = \{3,4\}$

$S_{4} = \{5,6,8,9,16\}$

$S_{5} = \{7,10,12,15,18,25,27,32,64,81,256,512,65536\}$

Notice that the largest members in sets $S_{2}$ through $S_{5}$ can be expressed as $2$, $2^{2}$, $2^{2^2}$ and $2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}$, respectively.  If the pattern holds, then the greatest number in $S_{6}$ is equal to $2^{65536}$; thus I will not try to list the members in further $S_{k}$.  But we have enough information to describe the sequence as $(1,1,1,2,5,13, \ldots)$, and there are several candidates in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.  So what's the sequence?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** $\mathcal{D}_{r_{\text{min}}}$ has an alternative nonnumerical definition (see Theorem 2.7 in Section 2.8 of arXiv:2102.02777):

**Definition 4.** Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote the Dyck language. The *standard minimal RPF language*, denoted by $\mathcal{D}_{r_{\text{min}}}$, is the set
\begin{equation}
\{d \in \mathcal{D} \mid (\;{'})()){'} \text{ is not a substring of } d\;)\;\wedge\;(\;{'})(){'} \text{ is not a suffix of } d\;) \}.
\end{equation}

Thus my question can be answered by providing a formula for the number of Dyck words of semilength $k$ not containing the substring ${)())}$ or the suffix ${)()}$, where $k \ge 0$.

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N_n$ be the number of words of semilength $n$ in
$$\{d \in \mathcal{D} \mid (\;{'})()){'} \text{ is not a substring of } d\;)\;\wedge\;(\;{'})(){'} \text{ is not a suffix of } d\;) \}.$$

Then $N_0 = N_1 = 1$, and similarly to Catalan numbers for $n\geq 2$, we have a recurrence:
\begin{split}
N_n &= \sum_{i=0\atop i\ne n-2}^{n-1} N_i N_{n-1-i} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} N_i N_{n-1-i} - N_{n-2}
\end{split}
It follows that the generating function $F(x):=\sum_{n\geq 0} N_nx^n$ satisfies the identity:
$$F(x) = 1 + xF(x)^2 - x^2F(x),$$
implying that
$$F(x) = \frac{1+x^2 - \sqrt{1-4x+2x^2+x^4}}{2x}.$$

In OEIS, your sequence is [A082582](https://oeis.org/A082582), which also gives the number of Dyck words of semilength $n$ with no `(())`. It is also the shifted [A086581](https://oeis.org/A086581), i.e., the number of Dyck words of semilength $n-1$ with no `))((`. It is also almost [A025242](https://oeis.org/A025242).

Comment: Thank you so much, @Max!  It turns out I guessed right, and the next time I revise arXiv:2102.02777, I will be able to change Section 5.1 ("The Significance of OEIS Sequence A082582") to replace a conjecture with a theorem...  You rock!